# ibm Cloud private console Not coming after installation

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud-private

I have installed the Ibm private cloud private with 3 nodes. MASTER,PROXY worker and management are configured on all the nodes. I also added vsphere cloud provider configuration in the config.yaml before those installation.
Installation is successful and i got the url for console http://proxy_vip:8443. But i cannot access the console. The port 8443 is not listening.
When i checked the pod status i got the below output.
 [i found this issue while running  'kubectl -s 127.0.0.1:8888 -n kube-system get pods. Other pods are running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBcdL.jpg)

Comment: Examin logs from pods that are crashing.

Comment: When checking the logs of the pods or container its coming like

Comment: Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ICP 2.1.0 installation, if the pods is CrashLoopBackOff, and kubectl logs or docker logs command shows 'Illegal instruction (core dumped)' error, you need to check your CPU information by command 'cat /proc/cpuinfo'. Ensure your CPU has 'sse4_2' flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the POD using kubectl delete pod icp-router -n kube-system. It should reinitialize the POD.

Comment: i have done that..still i cam getting the CrashLoopBackOff status

Comment: When i am checking the log of the pod and docker i getting the below output
"Illegal instruction (core dumped)"

Answer (score 0):

The admin console will be available at https://master_ip:8443/console. If the port isn't listening, then you can confirm the health of the `icp-router` pod(s):

```
kubectl -n kube-system get pods -o wide | grep icp-router
```

The output will show you the pod which is used to serve access to the web console. If it's not running or in a bad state, then your web console may not be accessible. If you can post logs from the container, then it may provide more insight into what's going on within your cluster:

```
kubectl -n kube-system logs icp-router-[XXXXX]
```